# Windows Phone 8 Media Elemaent has error

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I use media element to play a video online. It's okie when I played it on emulator. But when I test on lumia 520, It only plays 5-10 minutes then it has a error and back to the home screen.

How should I go about fixing it? I think that it is not enough ram memory.

Answer (score 0):

Narrow down the root cause.

1. Try other videos and note what happens with them. Use differing lenths.
2. Try videos which are not streamed, but local to the phone with greater lengths.
3. If possible, put a try catch block around the player or within its interactions in code behind., verify its not throwing an error. If it is promote the error (at least for now) to a bound text block so you can seen the error.
4. Subscribe to [MediaElement.MediaFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Media Ended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to see if that gives any indication of what is happening.
5. Can you fully stream the file to the phone then play it locally, then remove the file? Maybe separating that code will give a better experience.

Comment: @Carson I surmise not, but that is a question you may want to ask in a separate post.